# Digital compass without a magnetic field sensor?

Tags: android, compass-geolocation, magnetometer

How is it possible, that a Phone can have a digital compass but no magnetic field sensor? In the German data speciation below there a two different sensors: magnet field sensor (Magnetfeldsensor) and compass (Digitaler Kompass) listed.
The Huawei P9 has a compass but no magnetic field sensor. 
See under “Ortung/Sensoren”.

http://www.sortierbar.de/smartphone/huawei-p9

What is are the differences between these sensors? 
Can I get from the compass magnet field data?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, many devices come with digital compass. But it may be present in one of the two forms.

1.) Magnetic compass (also called magnetometer)

2.) Electronic compass

In the former case, the magnetometer has 3-axes which align themselves along the coordinates at which the device is present. This is a hardware based technology and is therefore quite accurate. The electronic compass on the other hand, provides the directions by connecting with the GPS.